# PHP variable inside a Javascript function outputs the variable and not the value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

What I want to do is that only when I click on a `div` with `id="$project['slug']"`, it will load the `iframe` inside that `div`.
So, i removed the `src` attribute from the `iframe`, and add it on `onclick` event.
I have this in my `HTML/PHP`:

```
<div class="box" id="<?=$project['slug']?>" onclick="load_frame();">
    <iframe id="frame_<?=$project['slug']?>" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

`Js`:

```
function load_frame() {
    id = location.hash.replace('#', '');
    var source = "<?php echo $project['video']; ?>";
    $('#frame_'+id).attr("src", source);
}
```

Unfortunately, when I inspect the `iframe` it shows: `src="<?=$project['video']?>"` instead of the value that the variable holds.
Do you have any idea what i am doing wrong?
thank you!

Comment: are u using external js ???

Comment: Seems you mix asp and php syntax. Change = to echo

Comment: @NipunJain Yes, i am using external js.

Comment: Think about what you're doing. A .js file is delivered to the browser as is, not passed through PHP (by default), so there's no way to insert PHP variables into it. Put the video URL into a [data attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) instead.

Comment: @DCoder Thanks so much for the tip! I learned something today :) It works this way too, but i gave accept to Amith for he provided a more complex answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is a client side language and have access only to the DOM elements once they have been rendered. So what you need to do is store `$project['video']` variable in a hidden field and then using the `id` of that field get access to the rendered data.

Also, i noticed that you should use `<?php` instead of `<?`

You may try something like this.

```
<div class="box" id="<?php echo $project['slug']; ?>">
    <iframe id="frame_<?php echo $project['slug']; ?>" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $project['slug']; ?>" value="<?php echo $project['video']" />
</div>
```

Then in jQuery do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.box').click(function(){
        var slug = $(this).attr('id');
        var source = $('input#' + slug).val();
        $('iframe#' + slug).attr("src", source);
    });
});
```

Comment: oops, forgot to change the iframe statement to use `slug` var. Updated!

Answer (score 1):

add hidden input on  html page

```
 <input type="hidden" id="hidsource" value="<?php echo $project['video']" />
```

edit your function in js like this

```
function load_frame() {
id = location.hash.replace('#', '');
$('#frame_'+id).attr("src", $('input#hidsource').val());
```

}

hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

You might not have the [shorthand syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) enabled on the server. Try standard PHP instead:

```
<?php echo $project['slug']; ?>
```